# Use a scope variable to look up object field in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use one scope variable as the field name to another object inside the angular view.

Example:
I have a variable called `monthYear` that is changed in a select box.
Based on that selection I want to look up that field in another object and display it.
Say the array of objects is called `objs[]` and `monthYear = 2017Jan`.
I want to look up the field `2017Jan` and display it for the first object in the array.

If I do this, it works: `{{objs[0][2017Jan]}}`

I need it to work dynamically, so I'm trying this: `{{objs[0][{{monthYear}}]}}`.

This is throwing an error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 10 of the expression [objs[1][{{monthYear] starting at [{monthYear].`

Comment: I seriously doubt that `{{objs[0][2017Jan]}}` works.

Answer (score 3):

### Use

### `{{objs[0]+" "+monthYear}}`

coz angularJS expressions are much like JavaScript expressions it contain literals, operators, and variables like {{ 1 + 3 }} or {{ fristVariable + " " + secondVariable }}

### See, [also this short demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tauseefnaqvi/zotLL27t/)